# How to solve "Unsupported config option for services.secrets" error after running docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

After running the following command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

I get this error message

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.secrets: 'db_password'
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/app/
      - ./src/node_modules:/usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      DB_NAME: "testdb"
      DB_USER: /run/secrets/db_user
      DB_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_user
      - db_password
  db:
    build: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db/
      - ./src/node_modules:/usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "websitedb"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_user
      - db_password
  secrets:
    db_user:
      file: ./db_user.txt
    db_password:
      file: ./db_pass.txt
```

This is my **Docker version**:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.3
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

I have already read several posts on this but I can't solve it. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you try create the secret beforehand using `docker secret create` and then in the secrets section change `file` to `external: true`?

Comment: I have tried it, but I get unfortunatelly the same error message.

Comment: I don't know the cause of this error. can you try change the name of the secret and see what happen?

Comment: I know it's an old one, but since I've ran into it today, I put my answer here : `secrets` (the main one, with the files...) must be at top level and not under "services"

Comment: @laudeon you should've posted it as the answer. Thanks.